# Can I use C++ stl in avr-gcc?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c, avr-gcc

I have implemented [C++ queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/) in my codes, those I run on my PC.

Now I'm programming an ATmega128 micro-controller to implement a `.c` code. Can I use that `queue`.

Will it work?

If not please suggest me a `queue` to implement.

Comment: no, you cannot use a C++ standard library queue in in C code. Also, a lot of the paradigms about lifetime of objects and memory handling underlying the C++ standard queue are questionable on microcontrollers to way to resource-intense for an ATmega128. C++ is **not** C with a bit of syntactic sugar. So, find a microcontroller C library that offers a queue.

Comment: Using C++ on any 8 bit MCU is an extremely bad idea. Overall, in order to use C++ on _any_ MCU, you must have a deep knowledge of how C++ code is translated to machine code, or otherwise that language will be nothing but harmful bloat. Using a legacy 8 bit MCU for new projects in the year 2019 isn't the best of ideas either.

Answer (score 5):

It is very well possible to use C++ on the AVR. Arduino has been doing it for ages. Unfortunately, avr-g++ does not ship with a C++ standard library (the successor to the old STL), so you have to rely on C++ core language features. C++, just like C, has many features that don't map well to small microcontrollers; you need to find out which ones. For starters, exceptions, RTTI (`typeid`), `new`/`delete`, and anything that requires those (especially standard library containers like `vector`, `string` and `queue`) don't really work here. Typical microcontroller programs use ring buffers and fixed arrays instead.

On the other hand, classes (including virtual functions), templates/Metaprogramming, `constexpr`, proper constants, avoiding macros, function overloads and RAII can be put to good use without sacrificing efficiency.

To compile C++ code, substitute calls to `avr-gcc` with calls to `avr-g++`. Make sure to use a recent version, since C++ support is in active development.

Comment: "To compile C++ code, substitute calls to avr-gcc with calls to avr-g++" -- i'm not 100% sure about this specific platform, but typically gcc uses file extension to determine file type, so `avr-gcc` should be able to compile C++ just fine. On other platforms, `g++` vs `gcc` changes whether libstdc++ is linked by default, so if this is not available for AVR I suspect there is actually no difference...

Answer (score 2):

You can use C++ with avr-gcc but not STL. I'm writing `std` for avr-gcc, except the code that use dynamic memory (so you can't use std::vector or std::queue) and exceptions. You can check my implementation:

https://github.com/amanuellperez/mcu/tree/master/src/std

It compiles with avr-gcc-9.2.0.

Comment: sounds cool, i was working on these type of project. semester ended, so did the project. btw, thanks. maybe i'll go through the whole library and learn something new.

Comment: Sorry, re-reading my answer I wrote 'you can use std::vector', but with my library you can't because I'm not planning in implementing dynamic memory for avr. Sorry for my spelling mistake.